# Can't install wondows 8.1 from 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I've set up my laptop (HP 4540s) to Boot from DVD by going to boot setup and click on **optical CD DRIVE** .

i put the Windows 8.1 DVD in my laptop and restart again , but nothing happend and windows run , **I can't get the blue page with Install Now Button** .

Any Idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't installed Windows 8.1 from disc before, are you sure it's a bootable disc?

Comment: How can i know ?

Comment: Well, usually if it doesn't boot then it's not a bootable disc.  You can try reinserting the disc while Windows is running and waiting for an auto-play, or opening the folder in windows explorer and looking for an executable.

Comment: yes it has setup.exe , now i insert win 7 DVD and same thing happend ,can't boot

Comment: I've only upgraded to 8.1 from 8 through the Windows Store/Windows Update, (can't remember which exactly), but if your cd has a setup.exe, you should just be able to run that.

Comment: Did you download as iso or did you get disk from a store

Comment: yes i got the cd from store

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are inadvertently interchanging the terms CD and DVD or not. That said, the way you explained it, it seems you are trying to get a CD player to read a DVD. That won't happen. CDs can be read by DVD player but DVDs cannot be read by CD player. 
You could copy all the files from the DVD using an appropriate reader/DVD player on another computer to a fresh flash/thumb drive with enough space and then use it to install the OS on your machine. The BIOS must be set to read USB drive as first boot device. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart again once you've changed the boot order. While it is rebooting you will want to change the boot order, usually this can be done by pressing F8 or esc, etc. Change the disk to boot before you hard-drive (with the disk already in) and let it continue.

While this would be your immediate solution for your method of installing windows, it would probably be easier to open the disc while the computer is running and clicking the setup, which will take care of everything for you.

BTW Windows 10 is available and will be released as an inplace upgrade for all windows 8 and 8.1 systems for free (I believe) in the near future.

Comment: FYI: I'm not sure Windows 8 qualifies for the upgrade, Windows 8.1 does though.  Windows 8.1 is a free upgrade from Windows 8 though.

Comment: @JohnieKarr Windows 10 claims that it is also releasing an in place upgrade for even windows 7. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade

Comment: Yes, Windows 7, and 8.1 are eligible for a free upgrade.  I don't think Windows 8 is included in that list.  From the fine print here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade "Devices must be connected to the internet and have Windows Update enabled. Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8.1 Update required"  The paragraph goes on to say that Windows 8 is excluded from the free upgrade offer.

Comment: @JohnieKarr Ah you're right. I assumed that since they were supporting 7 and didn't explicitly (missed the fine print) say 8.0 that it was supported. Looks like they want you to go to 8.1 first (Probably b/c it supports the "in place upgrade" process better). I'm sure it's still possible to install 10 on a 8.0 rig though, but it would have to be a clean install.